# How to deal with MSAL configurations for both debug and production Android app?

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated signing in to Azure AD using MSAL in android app. For app registration in Azure AD I used debug key store. This works fine in Android Studio debug environment.

I'm now ready to build a release apk. I know that I need to create a new signature hash on the release keystore.  I wonder what a recommended practice is. Should I update the existing (i.e. debug) app registration in ADD or should I create a new app registration for the production app?

Comment: Good question. I come from web apps background and we do register a new application for production for many reasons. They include debugging/testing without messing production registration and security concerns on return urls (in dev you register localhost for example). Since I dont have Android development background, I will leave this comment instead of an answer.

Comment: hi @bdristan, you said there would be different msal configurations for android debug or release app. Can you brief me more about it. I have done only debug configurations and my app is running very well and haven't done any release msal configs and I am suppossing that is the reason, its crashing while invoking msal method "rnmsal.createpublicclientapplication" ! Can you please brief me about this.. That would help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087345/msal-is-not-working-on-android-release-build-react-native

Answer (score 1):

## Development

### Option 1

You can use the automatically signing certificate generated by the Android SDK installation, **debug.keystore**, which can be found on

> **Windows:** %HOMEPATH%\.android
> **Linux:** ~/.android

> debug.keystore password: **android**

#### Windows environment*

I sincerely recommend executing these tasks on the old-school `cmd.exe` or any WSL terminal.

*PowerShell Core uses UTF-8 as the default character encoding for displaying text, whereas OpenSSL may use a different character encoding, such as ASCII.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

#### Linux environment

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Copy this hash and paste it into Azure's respective `Android Redirect URIs`.

[image]

#### Caveat

This approach implies that each team member involved in the project should register their corresponding hash on Azure.

### Option 2

Create your signing key certificate using the JDK tool `keytool`. After that, you must share it with the team,

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore your_keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -alias your_alias
```

- Keep in mind that the `keytool` used to read this signing key must match the version that was used to create it.

Now, to generate the required Azure hash signature:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias your_alias -keystore your_keystore.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

You must configure the app gradle file for this new signing key.

## Production

For security matters, I guess every app released on Play Console automatically receives a signing key certificate.

So, to generate the Azure signature hash for your production Android app:

On [Play Console](https://play.google.com/), navigate to your app dashboard page and, on the left menu, click on **Setup** to expand it. Click on **App singing** and select the tab **App signing** and download the **App signing key certificate**

[image]

[image]

#### Generating production Azure signature hash

After the **.der** file has been downloaded, execute:

##### Windows (cmd.exe)

```
 type your_file.der | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

##### Linux

```
 cat your_file.der | openssl sha1 -binary | base64
```

[image]

Now, just copy the resulting hash to Azure like you've done before for debugging.